# pass variables to the .tp file from .php modules vitger

Tags: vtiger

i am new in vtiger and trying to redesign my account list. I am trying to get array in ListViewContents.tpl from modules account but i failed. any one know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: i created function in modules->accounts->models->listview.php   but dont know how to use this function to get variable in ListViewContents.tp.

Comment: i want to get array in ListViewContents.tp so i can use loop there and echo them.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive it using following way:

Inside xyz.php file:

```
 function process(Vtiger_Request $request) {
     $viewer = $this->getViewer($request);
     $myArr = array('age'=>'1','name'=>'xyz');
     $viewer->assign('CUSTOM_ARR', $myArr);
     return $viewer->view('filename.tpl', $yourModuleName, 'true');
 }
```

In filename.tpl => Traverse the array which you have passed in xyz.php file

```
{foreach item=VALUE key=NAME from=$CUSTOM_ARR}
     {$VALUE['age']}
{/foreach}
```